# Creating a function that asks an input then prints with two possible answers then asks another input and prints another response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want to make a function in python that asks for your name, and gives a personalized response for a certain name, then a general greeting for any other name, then after that has finished it asks for a number that has to be correct, printing a possible two response depending on whether it is correct and incorrect. the problem I'm having is it asks for both inputs before responding to both, I want it to ask the first input, respond then ask the next one. many thanks in advance.

```
nameinput = str(input("What is your username? "))
namegreet = str("Welcome " + nameinput)
secretnum = int(input("What is your secret number? "))
master = str("fly")

def login():
    if (nameinput) == master:
        print("Hope ye be well, master creator fly.")
    else:
        print(namegreet) 
    
    if (secretnum) == 13:
        print(str("Access granted"))
    else:
        print(str("Initiating self destruct!"))

login()
```

iv tried making two separate functions to no avail, and my lack of knowledge and experience is holding me back from trouble shooting further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output by putting the first four lines of code inside the function body.

```py
def login():

    nameinput = input("What is your username? ")
    namegreet = "Welcome " + nameinput
    master = "fly"

    if nameinput == master:
        print("Hope ye be well, master creator fly.")
    else:
        print(namegreet) 
    
    secretnum = int(input("What is your secret number? "))

    if secretnum == 13:
        print("Access granted")
    else:
        print("Initiating self destruct!")

login()
```

**Remember:**

> Execution always begins at the first statement of the program.
> Statements are executed one at a time, in order, from top to bottom.
> Function definitions do not alter the flow of execution of the
> program, but remember that statements inside the function are not
> executed until the function is called. Function calls are like a
> detour in the flow of execution. Instead of going to the next
> statement, the flow jumps to the first line of the called function,
> executes all the statements there, and then comes back to pick up
> where it left off.

For more information:

https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/thinkcspy/Functions/FlowofExecutionSummary.html

I hope this helps.